# How to rename variables by searching for specific letter and letter orders in R and change it to another variable

Tags: r, rstudio

I am incredibly new to R. and am working on a project where it takes the variables of a column are different countries. however, some are spelled differently, or named differently. forexample some variables for "United states" would be "USA", "Ahem....Amerca", "'merica", "USSA" "USAUSAUSA". I want to be able to rename them simply to "United States" as well as only keep variables that are/resemble "United states", "Canada" and "United Kingdom" and omit/delete the entire row completely.

I have been thinking about using multiple if-statements inside a for-loop or using case_when. but im not entirely sure how to actually write the code to do it.

## im looking to look through one column with 2460 rows and look for specific words and order of letters and change it to "United States"

CandyData <- #is the dataframe the column is in

```
for ( row in 1:length(CandyData))
{
  if (x == "USA"| "Ahem...Amerca"|"merica"|"USSA"|"USAUSAUSA")
{x = "United States" }
else if 
{x.omit }
}
```

I don't really have any errors because I haven't been able to make it work properly.

Comment: Please update your post with a reproducible example covering all the cases you have with an expected output. Also read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RonakShah Hi Im new to stackoverflow so im not entirely sure how to include a small dataset into my question

Comment: dont use `==` for more tha none thing, use `%in%`

Comment: to include data type `dput(head(data))` and paste the output into your question

Comment: @FelixChan Hi, best is to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. a toy example as minimal as possible but still producing your issue while being copy-pastable and immediately runable.

Comment: when i pasted my dput(head(data)) this is what i receive"structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)"), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, it is very important to provide a reproducible example. It helps people who may want to help you! Otherwise, it could be time-consuming...

That said, you don't need a loop for doing it (actually, it's not advisable to use loops in R inadvertently, once it usually works better with vectorized alternatives).

Let's assume that the column you're working is called "Country":

```
# Update wrong values
wrong_names <- c("USA", "Ahem...Amerca", "merica", "USSA", "USAUSAUSA")
CandyData$Country[CandyData$Country %in% wrong_names] <- "United States"

# Select lines for target-countries only
CandyData[CandyData$Country %in% c("United States", "Canada", "United Kingdom"), ]
```

I hope it helps!
Best

Comment: Hi This really Helped thank you so much. However, the last portion doesn't seem to delete the other rows that arent "United States", "Canada", and "United Kingdom" is there a way to do this?